# Optimal storage of the list of Strings in the database

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have an Entity:

```
public class BookFilter {

     @Id
     private Integer id;
     private List <String> bookId;
     private String filterId;

     public BookFilter (List <String> bookId, String filterId) {
         this.bookId = bookId;
         this.filterId = filterId;
     }
}
```

and

```
public class BookAvailability {

    @Id
    private Integer id;
    private String bookId;
    private String type;
    private String term;
    private Instant dateFrom;
    private Instant dateTo;
}
```

how to optimally store it in the database?

Multiple books can be in multiple filters, and I have to query for filterId to get the bookId list. Something tells me that the JSON field will not be optimal?

```
CREATE TABLE `asset_global_filter`
(
    `id`        INTEGER,
    `asset_uid` JSON,
    `filter_id` VARCHAR(38) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
    ENGINE = InnoDB
    DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;
```

In the Criteria API, I have a condition that bookId must be equal for both entities and filterId = the specified value. Maybe model it like below? But how do I reflect in an Entity that I have many rows and convert them to a list?

```
CREATE TABLE `asset_global_filter`
(
    `id`        INTEGER,
    `asset_uid` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `filter_id` VARCHAR(38) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
    ENGINE = InnoDB
    DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from the description of your question, what you need to have in place is a `ManyToMany` relationship, between a `BookFilter` object and a `Book` object.

Suppose the following example:

```java
@Data
@Entity(name = "BookFilter")
@Table(name = "book_filter")
public class BookFilter {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "book_filter_sequence", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "book_filter_sequence", sequenceName = "book_filter_sequence", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;

    private String filterId;

    @ManyToMany(
        cascade = {
            CascadeType.PERSIST,
        CascadeType.MERGE
    }
    )
    @JoinTable(
        name = "filter_books",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "bookfilter_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "book_id")
    )
    private Set<Book> books = new HashSet<>();

}
```

```java
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "book")
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "book_sequence", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "book_sequence", sequenceName = "book_sequence", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;

    @NaturalId
    private String name;

    private String author;

    private String publisher;

    private String plot;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "books")
    @ToString.Exclude
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private Set<BookFilter> filters = new HashSet<>();

}
```

With both in place, you can go ahead and query using the `BookFilter` entity and have the JPA provider (hibernate in this case) return back the associated set of `Book` belonging to the `BookFilter` in question.

Comment: Not exactly like that.
I am using the Criteria API to create dynamic queries.
I don't have an object like a book, I only operate on bookId in this microservice.